# Get android.gms.location.Geofence gps location details/coordinates - point of crossing the fence?

Tags: geofencing, android-gps, android-geofence

Is it possible to get `Geofence` gps location details - i.e. point of crossing the fence?

1. I set up a geofence at location x,y, radius
2. I cross the fence my location is **x2, y2**

How do I easily get x2, y2 without calling GPS request again?

```
class GeofenceLocationReceiver: BroadcastReceiver() {
  [...]

  override fun onReceive(context: Context?, intent: Intent?) {
    val geofencingEvent = GeofencingEvent.fromIntent(intent)
    if (geofencingEvent.hasError()) {
      val errorMessage = GeofenceStatusCodes.getStatusCodeString(geofencingEvent.errorCode)
      Log.e(Category.LOCATION, "GEOFENCE result has errors: $errorMessage")
      return
    }
    if (geofencingEvent.geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_ENTER || geofencingEvent.geofenceTransition == Geofence.GEOFENCE_TRANSITION_EXIT) {

      geofencingEvent.triggeringGeofences.firstOrNull()?.let {
        val geofenceId = it.requestId
        // HERE - HOW TO GET X2, Y2 - GPS coordinates?
      }
    } else {
       Log.e(Category.LOCATION, "INVALID TYPE")
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[geofencingEvent.getTriggeringLocation()](https://developers.google.com/android/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/GeofencingEvent#getTriggeringLocation()) returns a [Location](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location.html)
which has [getLatitude()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#getLatitude()) and [getLongitude()](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/location/Location#getLongitude())

The Location (x2,y2) is the same for each triggered Geofence so no reason to call it in your iterator.

```
Location location = geofencingEvent.getLocation();
double x2 = location.getLongitude();
double y2 = location.getLatitude();
```